# Testing filetypes in bash scripts and using the appropriate commands to unpack them

Tags: bash, scripting

As of the moment I'm making a bash script that unpacks tarballs to install them. I'm on the part that unpacks the tarballs into a directoy. This is the script:

```
#!/Bin/bash/

# This program auto-installs tarballs for you.
# I designed this for Linux noobies who don't
# know how to install tarballs. Or, it's for
# people like me who are just lazy, and don't
# want to put in the commands ourselves.

echo "AutoTar v1.1"
echo "Gnu GPL v2.1"
read -p "Path to tarball:" pathname
cd "${pathname/#~/$HOME}"
    ls $pathname
       read -p "Please enter the file you wish to complile..." filename
if [-a $filename] == false
   then 
   echo "File does not exist! Exiting the program."
if  [[ ${filename -d} ==*.tar.gz ]]
 then
    tar -xzf $filename 
 done
else if
     [[ ${filename -d} ==*.tgz ]]
then
    tar -xzf $filename
 done
else if
   [[ ${filename -d} ==*.tar.bz2 ]]
then
    tar -xjf $filename
done
ls $pathname
echo -n "Please enter the directory of the file you have just unpacked...:"
read directory
cd $directory
```

What I need to do is use an if statement in order to detect the file and use the appropriate command, however I am not quite sure how to do this. With the current code I have, I simply get the error:

```
autotar.sh: line 18: conditional binary operator expected
autotar.sh: line 18: syntax error near `==*.tar.gz'
autotar.sh: line 18: `if  [[ ${filename -d} ==*.tar.gz ]]'
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. Fix everything it finds, then come back.

Comment: (I'd actually suggest temporarily deleting your question while you do that to avoid downvotes, and undeleting it when done if you still have questions).

Comment: ...well, actually, your code's bad enough that shellcheck can't parse it. Okay, an answer here might be needed.

Comment: BTW, in general, `read`ing parameters from stdin is bad form. It's much easier for folks to automate use of your programs if you take arguments from the command line instead.

Comment: BTW, if I were going to write a script for this kind of purpose, I'd make an empty directory before starting (as with `mktemp -d`), unpack into that directory -- then you can look inside the directory to see what files the unpack process created, and move whatever subdirectory/files/whatnot were created to a destination as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that a file doesn't exist:

```
if [[ ! -e $filename ]]; then ## works in bash or other ksh derivatives only
```

...or, for compatibility with older shells:

```
if [ ! -e "$filename" ]; then ## works in any POSIX shell
```

If you want to check for an extension:

```
if [[ $filename = *.tar.gz ]]; then ## works in bash or other ksh derivatives only
```

...or, to check for one of many extensions, consider a `case` statement instead:

```
# this works in any POSIX shell
[ -e "$filename" ] || { echo "$filename does not exist" >&2; exit 1; }

# this, too, works in any POSIX shell
case $filename in
  *.tar.gz|*.tgz)   tar -xzf "$filename" ;;
  *.tar.bz2|*.tbz2) tar -xjf "$filename" ;;
  *.tar.xz|*.txz)   xz -d <"$filename" | tar -xv ;;
  *.zip)            unzip "$filename" ;;
 esac
```

---

Note, in particular:

- **Whitespace is essential**. You cannot leave out spaces. `[ "$foo" = 1 ]` is a valid and correct statement, whereas `[$foo=1]` and `[ "$foo" =1]` are syntax errors, and `[ "$foo"==1 ]` always returns true, no matter what value `foo` has.
- **Excepting specific exemptions, quoting expansions is mandatory for correct behavior**. If you're not sure, the safe thing is to use them: You can leave out quotes in `[[ ]]` or `case` only these have special syntax rules that make them optional. If you were using `[ ]` instead, then you would need to use them: `if [ ! -e "$filename" ]`.

  However, `tar -xzf "$filename"` or `echo "$filename"` or `ls "$pathname"` all need spaces to work correctly with interesting files or path (try names with spaces in testing your software; names with glob characters are another frequent cause of potential bugs, especially when combined).
- **`[` is just a synonym for `test`; it's a command, not special syntax, and commands follow normal parsing rules.** Just as you can't run `test$foo=false`, you can't run `[$foo=false]` or `[-a $filename]`; it needs to be `[ -e "$filename" ]` (unary use of `-a` is not present in the POSIX specification for `test`, hence the switch to `-e`).